# Twisted - kick specific client

Tags: python, client, twisted

I want to disconnect specific user in twisted based application. Can somebody explain how I can do it ?

Comment: Yes or when somebody connect it'll generate some connection identifier and then close connection with given identifier.

Answer (score 1):

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

bannedIPs = ["127.0.0.1"]

class HelloResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    numberRequests = 0

    def render_GET(self, request):
        clientIP = request.getClientIP()

        if clientIP in bannedIPs:
            return "you are banned"

        self.numberRequests += 1
        request.setHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        return "I am request #" + str(self.numberRequests) + "\n"

reactor.listenTCP(8080, server.Site(HelloResource()))
reactor.run()
```

Comment: I don't want to ban sombody but just disconnect him while he is connected or disconnect him and ban him for 1-2 minutes.